# Retornar um JSON Array com shell script para usar no PHP

Tags: php, json, shell-script

Boa Noite Pessoal,
Estou me batendo com uma coisa a alguns dias.
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para se conectar via SSH em uma OLT com shell script e retornar os "Shows" para uma frontend web.

Tenho a seguinte pagina:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um arquivo shell script que conecta via SSH na OLT da o comando abaixo:

```
show interface gpon 1/1/1 onu
```

E joga o retorno do comando para a variável **list** onde trato o resultado dando alguns sed e awk.

```
list=`showOnu | sed '1,2d' | awk '{print $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $5}'`

    echo $list

    echo "<table class='table table-hover'>"
    echo "  <thead>"
    echo "    <tr>"
    echo "      <th scope='col'>ID</th>"
    echo "      <th scope='col'>Serial Number</th>"
    echo "      <th scope='col'>Oper State</th>"
    echo "      <th scope='col'>Name</th>"
    echo "      <th scope='col'></th>"
    echo "    </tr>"
    echo "  </thead>"
    echo "  <tbody>"

    for I in $list
    do
            idonu=`echo $I | cut -d, -f1`
            serialnumber=`echo $I | cut -d, -f2`
            name=`echo $I | cut -d, -f3`
            status=`echo $I | cut -d, -f4`
            echo "    <tr>"
            echo "      <th scope='row'>$idonu</th>"
            echo "      <td>$serialnumber</td>"
            echo "      <td>$name</td>"
            echo "      <td>$status</td>"
            echo "      <td class='text-right'><a href='onu_edit.php?oltid=1&oltinterface=1' class='btn btn-sm btn-info'>Editar</a></td>"
            echo "    </tr>"
    done
    echo "  </tbody>"
    echo "</table>"
```

Dentro do script eu ajusto a html para criar o resultado.

E uso isso no PHP para chamar o script na pagina:

```
<?php 
$a = popen('./conectOlt -f interfaceOnuList -a '.$olt['ip'].' -i '.$slot.' -e '.$olt['id'].'', 'r'); 
while($b = fgets($a, 2048)) { 
echo $b; 
ob_flush();flush(); 
} 
pclose($a); ?>
```

E gera o resultado que tenho na primeira imagem, até ai tudo certinho, esta funcionando bem.

Mas estava pensando aqui, não teria alguma forma de no lugar de criar o `<table>` no shell script criar um json e devolver apenas o json para o php e trabalhar com ele la criando a tabela direto no php.

Basicamente o que quero é criar um json com arrey e talvez usar um foreach no php para criar cada linha com as informações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, você pode criar o seu JSON todo como uma string, e no php você recebe essa string (como já faz com a tabela) mas no lugar de dar um `echo` nela você usa o método `json_decode` para coverter essa string em um objeto JSON, aí você consegue trabalhar com ele normalmente.
Veja este exemplo:

```
<?php
$json = '{
    "alunos": [{
        "nome": "Joao",
        "idade": 18
    }, {
        "nome": "Maria",
        "idade": 20
    }, {
        "nome": "Claudia",
        "idade": 30
    }]
}';
$jsonObj = json_decode($json,TRUE);
print_r($jsonObj["alunos"]);

?>
```

Pode testar o exemplo acima [aqui](https://repl.it/@MuriloPortugal/PHP-Testes)

Comment: Mano, desculpa a demora...
Mas me bati um pouco para fazer funcionar mas com o que me passou ajudou bastante.

Comment: @GiovaniCórdova, que bom que deu certo! Obs: Se a resposta lhe ajudou a resolver o problema por favor considere marca-la como correta para ajudar outras pessoas com uma dúvida parecida com a sua!